# Invalid JSON primitive: id

Tags: web-services, jquery, asmx

I cannot get the following function to work properly.  It seems to be serializing it wrong.  This is about the 5th iteration of different data variants.  I was originally just doing data: {'id': id} like I do at work with WCF, but with the ASMX it just isn't working.  It looks like it's serializing teh data as id=1234 instead of id:1234, but I'm fairly new to this.  Any help would be appreciated.  Oh, and I can call the service directly in the browser and it returns the data properly so I know it's not the service.

```
function getVentID(id) {
    //look up id in database and get VentID
    alert('id: ' + id);
    var jsdata = { "id": + id}
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: 'services/UserService.asmx/getVentID',
        data: jsdata,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
        },
        error: function (a, b, c) {
            alert('Error: ' + a.toString() + ' ' + b.toString() + " " + c.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

p.s. I know there are like 10 identical questions but none of them have answers that I could find or that worked for me.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The simplest possible fix would be to change the line beginning `var jsdata` to:

```
var jsdata = '{id:' + id + '}';
```

The problem is that jQuery is encoding jsdata as form data, not as json. The `dataType` parameter influences how the response is parsed, not how the POST data is encoded.

There's not actually any JSON serialization code in jQuery to the best of my knowledge. Apparently [John Resig suggests using Douglas Crockford's json2.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery/912247#912247).

To use it, add a script reference to json.js and then:

```
var jstext = JSON.stringify(jsdata, null, 2);
```

Comment: Well, technically that solved the error I posted, but now I get: Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027ID\u0027.","StackTrace":" at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod... etc  Any ideas?

Comment: I tried changing the case since the new error says ID instead of id but it didn't help and I don't even know if that's related...

Comment: Hmmm. I admit I don't quite know exactly what the asmx is expecting. What's an example of what you do directly in your browser that works? I can definitely help translate that to a jQuery call.

Comment: sblom if you're still around maybe you can update your accepted answer with my adjusted answer to help future googlers.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem right now.

You need pass the url in this format:

http://domain.com.br/service.asmx/method?objParam={q : "search"}

And in your service.asmx file, you need declare this method:

```
Public Function method(objParam As Dictionary(Of String, String)) 

End Function
```

---

In your code, looks like:

```js
function getVentID(id) {
  var jsdata = {
    "id": +id
  }
  var sData = JSON.stringify(jsdata); //convert your json in string
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url: 'services/UserService.asmx/getVentID',
    data: {
      id: sData
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(msg) {
      alert(msg.d);
    },
    error: function(a, b, c) {
      alert('Error: ' + a.toString() + ' ' + b.toString() + " " + c.toString());
    }
  });
}
```